# Add percentage to loading bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have a jquery ui loading bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 });
});
```

I wish to apply some sort of "real-time-loading" value to the bar.

I want to do it like:
 - Count down from X seconds - while it countdowns, the loading bar percentage is increasing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var seconds = 10;
function countdown() {
    if(seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: Math.round((seconds/10)*100) });
        if(seconds > 0) {
            setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
        }
    }
}
countdown();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`#progressbar` is a `<div>`, simply change the text of it to match the `value` property of the progressbar method. Style it whatever you like in CSS.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I want to:
Count down from X seconds - while it countdowns, the loading bar percentage is increasing.

(I don't have any countdown script).